# Linq 2 IndexedDB: how to retrieve last inserted auto-incremented key?

Tags: indexeddb, winjs

I am using IndexedDB (through Linq2IndexedDB nugget) in my Windows8 application to deal with local storage. I need to retrieve last auto-incremented ID inserted in my local database (the equivalent of mysql_insert_id). How can I proceed?

I retrieve my records with:

```
db.linq.from("favoriteSearches").select().then(function(searches) {
    // ....
});
```

But I have no trace of the key in *searches*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object store has a keyPath, the object will contain the key in the property defined in the key path.

If you didn't define an database configuration, linq2indexeddb runs in autogenerate mode. This means object stores and indexes are created when you need them. If this is the case and the object store is auto created, the keyPath for the object store is "Id" and in the return data you should find the key value in the "Id" property

Edit:
If you take the latest version of the linq2indexedDB lib 1.0.13 you will the key back when inserting data

```
db.linq.from("favoriteSearches").insert(data).then(function (args){ 
    var key = args.key;
    var data = args.data;
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support on Twitter and here. Indeed, I used the parameter dbConfig to specify the keyPath, and all is correct.

Not sure, but with the latest update, it seems the DBViewer is broken. Perhaps an issue in my code. Will investigate. :)

Comment: Tnx for mentioning the issue with the dbviewer, I'll look in to that ASAP. you can also make use of db.viewer to look inside the indexeddb if you configured it on the linq2indexeddb method. var db = linq2indexeddb("name", dbConfig, true) --> last parameter enables logging + viewer.